# Python tqdm process_map: Append list shared between processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, tqdm

I want to share a list to append output from parallel threads, started by `process_map` from `tqdm`. (The reason why I want to use `process_map` is the nice progress indicator and the `max_workers=` option.)

I have tried to use `from multiprocessing import Manager` to create the shared list, but I am doing something wrong here: My code prints an empty `shared_list`, but it should print a list with 20 numbers, correct order is not important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

```
import time
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map
from multiprocessing import Manager


shared_list = []

def worker(i):
    global shared_list
    time.sleep(1)
    shared_list.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    shared_list = manager.list()

    process_map(worker, range(20), max_workers=5)
    print(shared_list)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't specify what platform you are running under (you are supposed to tag your question with your platform whenever you tag a question with `multiprocessing`), but it appears you are running under a platform that uses `spawn` to create new processes (such as Windows). This means that when a new process is launched, an empty address space is created, a new Python interpreter is launched and the source is re-executed from the top.

So although you have in the block that begins `if __name__ == '__main__':` assigned to `shared_list` a managed list, each process in the pool that is created will be executing `shared_list = []` clobbering your initial assignment.

You can pass `shared_list` as the first argument to your worker function:

```py
import time
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map
from multiprocessing import Manager
from functools import partial

def worker(shared_list, i):
    time.sleep(1)
    shared_list.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    shared_list = manager.list()

    process_map(partial(worker, shared_list), range(20), max_workers=5)
    print(shared_list)
```

If `process_map` supported the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments in the same way as the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class does (**it appears that it does not**), then you could do:

```py
import time
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map
from multiprocessing import Manager

def init_pool(the_list):
    global shared_list
    shared_list = the_list

def worker(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    shared_list.append(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    shared_list = manager.list()

    process_map(worker, range(20), max_workers=5, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(shared_list,))
    print(shared_list)
```

**Comment**

This has nothing to do *per se* with your original problem, but for this type of problem you might want to consider using instead of a managed list to which your worker function (coincidentally named `worker`) appends elements and the order in which the elements are appended is non-deterministic since you do not have any control over the scheduling of the pool processes, a `multiprocessing.Array` instance initialized as follows:

```py
shared_list = Array('i', [0] * 20, lock=False)
```

And then you worker function becomes:

```py
def worker(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    shared_list[i] = i
```

Here the array is being stored in shared memory and there is not even a need for locked access since each invocation of `worker` is accessing a different index of the array. Accessing elements of a shared memory Array is *much* faster than accessing elements of a managed list. The only problem is that references to shared memory cannot be passed as arguments and we saw that `process_map` does not support the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments. So you would have to use lower-level methods. For example:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array
from tqdm import tqdm

def init_pool(the_list):
    global shared_list
    shared_list = the_list

def worker(i):
    time.sleep(1)
    shared_list[i] = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Preallocate 20 slots for the array in shared memory
    # And we don't require a lock if each worker invocation is accessing a different Array index:
    args = range(20)
    shared_list = Array('i', [0] * len(args), lock=False)

    with tqdm(total=len(args)) as pbar:
        pool = Pool(5, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(shared_list,))
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(worker, args):
            pbar.update(1)
    # print out elements one at a time:
    for elem in shared_list:
        print(elem)
    # print out all elements at once (must first convert to a regular list):
    print(list(shared_list))
```

**Comment 2**

I would avoid using `process_map`. This function is based on the `map` method of the `ProcessPoolExecutor.map` method, which is required to return results in an order corresponding to the elements of the *iterable* being passed, *not* in the order of completion. Imagine what happens if for some reason the process that is processing the first task submitted, `i` value 0 in our case, takes a very long time to process and turns out to be the last task completed. You would see the `tqdm` progress bar do nothing for a long time until that first submitted task completed. But when that happens we know that all the other submitted tasks have already completed and so the progress bar would jump from 0 to 100% instantaneously. Modify function `worker` as follows to see this in action:

```py
def worker(shared_list, i):
    if i == 0:
        time.sleep(5)
    else:
        time.sleep(.25)
    shared_list.append(i)
```

The code version I offered above that uses `Pool.imap_unordered` is allowed to returns results out of order and with the default *chunksize* value of 1, it will be in the order of completion. The progress bar will more smoothly progress.

**Comment 3**

There also seems to be a bug in `tqdm`. The following program demonstrates how you would use the low-level `tqdm` calls this time with the `concurrent.futures` module. Unfortunately, its `ProcessPoolExecutor` class (for multiprocessing) and `ThreadPoolExecutor` class (for multithreading) does not have an equivalent to the `imap_unordered` method. You have to use the `submit` method (whose `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` analog would be the `apply_async` method), which returns a `Future` instance on which you can call the `result` method to block for completion and to return the result of the submitted task). You would `submit` a bunch of tasks and store the returned `Future` instances perhaps in a list and then use the `as_completed` function call to be returned from that list the next completed `Future` instance that has completed.

This demo uses threading and creates a thread pool who size is 20 and submits 20 tasks, so all tasks should start at the same time. The sleep time for `worker1` is set to vary so that the smaller the value for the `i` argument, the longer the sleep time is. This program creates the pool and submits the tasks 4 times. The first time, the return values are just printed. The second time a `tqdm` progress bar is used. The results are as you would expect. The third time `worker2` is used with the `tqdm` progress bar. The difference is that for all values of `i != 0` the sleep time is a constant (.25 seconds), so that for `i` values 1, 2, ... 19, the tasks should complete at roughly the same time.  You would therefore expect to see the progress bar within a very short time jump to 95% and then wait for the `i == 0` task to complete. What you observe, however, is the opposite. The progress bar goes to 5% and hangs there for a long time and then jumps to 100%. The fourth case is using `worker2` with my own "progress bar", which behaves as you would expect.

This is `tqdm` 4.61.1 under Python 3.8.5. I have tested this under Windows and Linux. Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

```py
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from tqdm import tqdm
import sys

class MyProgressBar:
    def __init__(self, n_tasks):
        self._task_count = n_tasks
        self._completed = 0
        self.update()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print(file=sys.stderr)
        return False

    def update(self, count=0):
        self._completed += count
        print(f'\r{self._completed} of {self._task_count} task(s) completed.', end='', flush=True)

def worker1(i):
    if i == 0:
        time.sleep(8)
    else:
        time.sleep(5 - i/5)
    return i

def worker2(i):
    if i == 0:
        time.sleep(8)
    else:
        time.sleep(.25)
    return i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = range(20)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
        futures = [pool.submit(worker1, arg) for arg in args]
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            print(future.result())

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
        with tqdm(total=len(args)) as pbar:
            futures = [pool.submit(worker1, arg) for arg in args]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                future.result()
                pbar.update(1)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
        with tqdm(total=len(args)) as pbar:
            futures = [pool.submit(worker2, arg) for arg in args]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                future.result()
                pbar.update(1)

    # Works with my progress "bar":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
        with MyProgressBar(len(args)) as pbar:
            futures = [pool.submit(worker2, arg) for arg in args]
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                future.result()
                pbar.update(1)
```

Comment: I would like to add that I did not know there is a simple solution: process_map()
 returns a list of all the return values of the worker function. So I don't need to append to a special shared list within the worker function, I just return my value and it will end up in the list that's returned by process_map().

Comment: Yes --  I though that went without saying about all the map functions. I just thought you were trying to learn about managed structures (and shared memory), which are appropriate when simple return values are not sufficient for what you need to do.